# Python3 PID simulation for roket

Tags: python-3.x, simulation, pid

I'm building a model rocket but I'm having trouble getting my offline simulation to work properly.

When I run the simulation in "1-second mode" it works perfectly, but when I try to calculate the new position every millisecond it doesn't. The code is written in python3.

I send the code in "1-millisecond mode" I hope you can help.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

time=10*1000
potencia=2.73         #powerof engine
Pcont=5
Icont=0
Dcont=0

Brazo_fuerza=0.21        #moment arm
Inetia=0.083407294

Setpoint=0
dt=1

TVC=0
Angulo_veiculo=-20          #angel of rocket
Angulo_veiculo_ant=0        #angel of rocket vefore
Fuerza_ariba=0
Fuerza_lado=0
torque=0                   #tor
Accel_rotacion=0             #rotational acceleration
Sum=0
pos=0
acc=5

X1=[]
X2=[]

def PIDcal(Sum):

    e = Angulo_veiculo-Setpoint

    P=e*Pcont
    Sum+=e*dt
    I=Sum*Icont
    D=((Angulo_veiculo-Angulo_veiculo_ant)/dt)*Dcont

    PID=P+I+D

    PID=PID/3

    if PID > 5:
        PID=5
    elif PID < -5:
        PID=-5

    return PID, Sum

for t in range(time):
    Fuerza_lado=round(potencia*math.sin(math.radians(TVC)),acc)     #calcuate lateral force

    torque=round(Brazo_fuerza*Fuerza_lado,acc)                 #calculate torque

    Accel_rotacion=round((torque/Inetia),acc)                  #calculate rotational acceleration

    Angulo_veiculo+=round(math.degrees(Accel_rotacion)/1000,acc)     #calculate actual rotation of rocket

    if Angulo_veiculo > 181:
        Angulo_veiculo=-180
    elif Angulo_veiculo <-181:
        Angulo_veiculo=-180

    TVC, Sum=PIDcal(Sum)

    TVC=round(TVC*-1,acc)
    X1.append(TVC)
    X2.append(Angulo_veiculo)


plt.plot(range(time),X1,label = 'TVC')                      #plot
plt.plot(range(time),X2,label = 'Angulo_veiculo')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Thankes, sory for my bad English I'm from Spain.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a time step of 1 second (dt=1) in your PID controller. When you switch to a time step of 1 millisecond, you need to adjust your integral term accumulation accordingly.

Hope this helps (By the way your english sounds Great)